# Do people in life, engage, in reward, competition

Tags: psychology

This post is perhaps better suited to the psychology stack exchange.

It is about whether people in life engage in reward competition.

That is, given, an amount of effort, to obtain something, can a person, opt, for, choosing, the given reward, for the obtained effort (by making a choice between the different rewards, when, at all available, to choose from)?

Thank you.

Comment: Your commas in the final paragraph render it into gibberish.

Comment: Why would you ask a question with such an obvious answer?

Comment: Sorry it's not clear what your are getting to.